# OutputStream not converting into a String varible

Tags: java, multithreading, byte, runnable, outputstream

So I was going into this thinking it would be a simple 1 or 2 line code in order for me to convert the **OutputStream** into a String so that I can check it better with my logic.

So the code below is what I am currently working with. It **works just fine** if I just want to write **output** to the **console** and that's all. However, I am wanting to store that **output** as a **string**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Process p;

    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd");
        new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getErrorStream(), System.err)).start();
        new Thread(new SyncPipe(p.getInputStream(), System.out)).start();
        PrintWriter stdin = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
        stdin.println("cd C:/Local Apps/xxx/xxx/xxxx/eclipse");
        stdin.println("lscm login -r https://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:9443/ccm -n xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx -u itsme -P gr^34dbtfgt7y");
        stdin.close();

        p.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}

class SyncPipe implements Runnable {
    public SyncPipe(InputStream istrm, OutputStream ostrm) {
        istrm_ = istrm;
        ostrm_ = ostrm;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            for (int length = 0; (length = istrm_.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
                ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);                    
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private final OutputStream ostrm_;
    private final InputStream istrm_;
}
```

I'm wanting to get the data from this:

```
ostrm_.write(buffer, 0, length);
```

I've tried all sorts of things I found on google:

```
String string = new String(ostrm_.toString());
System.out.println(string);

String string = new String(ostrm_.toString("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(string);

final PrintStream blah = new PrintStream(ostrm_);
final String string = blah.toString();
System.out.println(string);

String blah = ostrm_.toString();
System.out.println(string);

byte[] blah = buffer;
String string = blah.toString();
```

I'm thinking I could use something like **OutputStreamWriter** but again, I can't seem to get it working. So it would be great if a Java guru can help me solve this issue that seems so easy it's hard....

**UPDATE 1** for boot-and-bonnet:

[image]

Comment: Getting data from an output steam doesn't make sense. You already supplied the data to write. So that's the data.

Comment: @user207421 You are correct *BUT* I am wanting to save it into a variable and not just write it out to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i finally got it!

```
String line;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(istrm_));

while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing things the very hard way. To run a command, in a particular working directory, and sending output to the console, use [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and [`inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()).

All of the code in the question can be reduced to:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c",
                       "lscm", "login",
                       "-r", "https://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:9443/ccm",
                       "-n", "xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx",
                       "-u", "itsme",
                       "-P", "gr^34dbtfgt7y")
            .directory(new File("C:/Local Apps/xxx/xxx/xxxx/eclipse"))
            .inheritIO()
            .start()
            .waitFor();
}
```

**UPDATE**

To gather all output from the command into a single string, you would first combine stdout and stderr by calling [`redirectErrorStream(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream(boolean)) instead of calling `inheritIO()`, then gather the output into a `String` using the appropriate character set.

The following uses the platform default [`Charset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html), since that is likely what the command outputs.

```
String[] command = {
        "cmd", "/c",
        "lscm", "login",
        "-r", "https://xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:9443/ccm",
        "-n", "xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx",
        "-u", "itsme",
        "-P", "gr^34dbtfgt7y" };
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(command)
        .directory(new File("C:/Local Apps/xxx/xxx/xxxx/eclipse"))
        .redirectErrorStream(true) // stderr > stdout
        .start();
p.getOutputStream().close(); // stdin < NUL
String output;
try (InputStream in = p.getInputStream()) {
    output = new String(in.readAllBytes());
}
int errorCode = p.waitFor();
```

```
System.out.print(output);
if (errorCode != 0)
    System.out.println("Program terminated with error code " + errorCode);
```

The code above is for Java 9+. For Java 7+, get `output` like this:

```
try (InputStream in = p.getInputStream()) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    for (int len; (len = in.read(buf)) > 0; )
        bytes.write(buf, 0, len);
    output = bytes.toString();
}
```

Comment: This does work but my question was how to get the output into a string variable.

Comment: Can you show how you would get the output using your way?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`readAllBytes()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes()) and create a `String` using the default charset:

```
System.out.println(new String(istrm_.readAllBytes()));
```

Comment: I dont have an option for **readAllBytes()**. See OP for the update on this.

Comment: Looks like it is available from Java 9

Comment: Ah that's why. I'm using 8.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
byte[] blah = buffer;
String string = new String(blah);
```